# django mysql db connection protocol

Tags: mysql, django, database

How can I specify connection protocol in db OPTIONS? If I use:

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
 ...
'OPTIONS': {
        'protocol': 'TPC',
    },
```

error is `'protocol' is an invalid keyword argument for this function`

I'm trying to set OPTIONS as on [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-OPTIONS) and here is [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html#option_general_protocol) It is because I want to establish connection to remote db with ssh tunnel.

Comment: Are you sure the option is valid? I did a short check and did not found it on documentation -- maybe valid though, but just wondering

Comment: @frlan I think it isn't. I don't know how to specify protocol except in `OPTIONS`

Comment: So going a step further: Why you want to define TCP? TCP should be the default anyway we are connection not by socket, but via IP

Comment: @frian well I'm trying to establish connection via ssh tunnel and access to the db remotely. When I'm connected to the server, in the terminal I must specify `--protocol=TPC` to establish connection with remote mysql db. `mysql -u X -pXX -h localhost --protocol=TCP XX`

Answer (score 7):

changing

```
'HOST': 'localhost',
```

to

```
'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
```

fix the problem. Using IP as host value driver is forced to use TPC protocol. In the case of localhost it use local file socket which won't work through the tunnel.

Comment: I have been bitten by this too! Thanks for the answer.